# What is the effect of switching noise?

Tags: power-supply

I am going to build a lab bench power supply using smps and LTC3780 step up and down regulator. Like a youtuber great scott built in a video which i will link below. Can such a bench power supply be used in laptop and mobile repair ?

What will be the effect of switching noise if I use that kind of supply in repair work ?

Video link https://youtu.be/wI-KYRdmx-E

Comment: What is the specification for the power supply and what does the schematic look like?

Comment: Check the video linked https://youtu.be/wI-KYRdmx-E

Comment: No, this is a question and answer site and you should write down what the power supply specification is and show a circuit diagram (even if it means you pausing the video and taking a screen capture). Please don't repeat in comments what you contained in the main question.

Comment: Cheap SMPS will have > 20mV pp ripple and may cause radio or RF interference and maybe some audio noise but still useful as a charger of DC test tool. Current limiter may not always protect connection failures if there is a large output storage cap.that can dump energy before current limit.  OK but not as good as professional lab supply., Sometimes   65W/85W laptop 19V supply  have switch universal step voltages  12~25V then add low voltage regulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What will be the effect of switching noise if I use that kind of supply in repair work ?*

That depends on what you will use the supply for when doing repair work.

*Can the supply be used as a replacement for an AC adapter?*

Probably yes, as an AC adapter is also a switched mode supply and will also have some ripple on its output voltage. Most laptops run from 19 V from an AC adapter, this voltage isn't used directly. There are many switching regulators inside the laptop as well which convert the 19 V to 5 V, 3.3V and 1.8 V for example.

*Can the supply be used instead of a battery?*

Usually yes unless the circuit relies on the low noise / ripple free output voltage of a battery. It depends on the device if this is the case. Cases where the supply ripple might be an issue are audio amplifiers, radio receivers and sensitive measurement equipment.

Even then, when using a supply which outputs a ripple on its output voltage, the device might still just work only with audible noise or measurement equipment might not perform as accurately as it should.

Comment: For example 3.3v or 1.8v is missing in any motherboard so my question is that will the output ripple destroy any other component or it will be safe to use ?

Comment: I think that it is highly unlikely that components would be destroyed under normal circumstances. But no guarantees, there can always be unexpected situations. Having **current limiting** on a bench supply and setting it properly is a good precaution to avoid most disasters.